# Stopping timer in an anonymous function jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, intervals

I have a timer that starts running when the scene loads. I am trying to stop it, but I think the issue is because it is in an anonymous function. Is there a way I can stop it from a button?

```js
$(function () {
var timer;
var secs = 0;
var mins = 0;
var timeField = document.getElementById("time");
timeField.innerHTML = "00:00";

function update(){
 if(secs == 59){
  mins++;
  secs = 0;
 } 
 else {
  secs++;
 }
 if(secs<10){
  timeField.innerHTML = mins + ':0' + secs;
 } 
 else {
  timeField.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
 } 
}

function start(){
 timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, 1000);
}

start(); 

});
$("#1").click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<body window.onload=function() {start();}>
 <div id="time"><span>00:00</span></div>

</body>

<button id="1"> One</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the click handler inside the anonymous function, so that it will have the same scope as the `timer` variable.

You can then add this within the click handler:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  var timer;
  var secs = 0;
  var mins = 0;
  var timeField = document.getElementById("time");
  timeField.innerHTML = "00:00";

  function update() {
    if (secs == 59) {
      mins++;
      secs = 0;
    } else {
      secs++;
    }
    if (secs < 10) {
      timeField.innerHTML = mins + ':0' + secs;
    } else {
      timeField.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
    }
  }

  function start() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      update()
    }, 1000);
  }

  start();

  $("#1").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body window.onload=function() {start();}>
  <div id="time"><span>00:00</span>
  </div>

</body>

<button id="1">One</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the timer's id which you have since you are saving a reference to timer.

So the following code would stop the timer:

`window.clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: @user2557504 It most certainly does.